# Unexpected Error from external database driver (11265)

Tags: delphi, odbc, firedac, paradox

Trying Delphi 10.2 Tokyo with Paradox using FireDAC ODBC bring gives the error:  Unexpected Error from external database driver (11265)

Answer (score -3):

A solution is to try one of these:
1. You need to give the admin authentication to odbc32.dll 
2. Permit the full access for the current user to odbc32.dll 
3. Change the ownership of odbc32.dll for the current user/admin 
4. You must install BDE (Borland Database Engine) to open the paradox DB Files. 5. go to control panel and open Data Source (odbc). After Open ODBC go to the Connection Pooling and Enable the polling for the Microsoft Access Driver(*mdb) and Driver do Microsoft Paradox (*.db) 
6. Add the File DSN to set the paradox DB Directory 
7. Create the User DSN for Driver do Microsoft Paradox 
8. Change the NET DIR Path to your paradox database folder.